# How to read config file (*.yaml *.properties) without spring framework

Tags: java, annotations, config

I have a project but not in spring, how can I use annotation to read content in config files like `*.yaml or *.properties` under resource package.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 16):

You can use SnakeYAML without Spring.

Download the dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.24'
```

Then you can load the .yaml (or .yml) file this way:

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                           .getResourceAsStream("youryamlfile.yaml"); //This assumes that youryamlfile.yaml is on the classpath
Map<String, Object> obj = yaml.load(inputStream);
obj.forEach((key,value) -> { System.out.println("key: " + key + " value: " + value ); });
```

[Reference.](https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml)

**Edit:** Upon further investigation, OP wants to know how to load properties in Spring boot. Spring boot has a built-in feature to read properties.

Let's say you have a application.properties sitting in src/main/resources, and in it there is an entry say `application.name="My Spring Boot Application"`, then in one of your classes annotated with `@Component` or any of its sub-stereotype annotations, one can fetch values like this:

```
@Value("${application.name}")
private String applicationName;
```

The property in application.property file is now bound to this variable `applicationName`

You could also have a application.yml file and have the same property written this way

```
application:
  name: "My Spring Boot Application"
```

You will get this property value the same way like last time by annotation a filed with `@Value` annotation.

Comment: I want to use annotation like `@Value` in spring-boot

Comment: You see your question? You said without Spring. In Spring Boot, it is even easier. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Is it possible without 3rd-party libraries?

Comment: I am afraid I am not aware.

Comment: @Faraz, I used the above code to read yml file that has : server: box1: host = "abcde". The system print statement has got key:server value:{box1{host="abcde"}}. Will this convert into server.box1.host?

Answer (score 2):

flat properties from yaml

```
import static java.lang.String.format;
import static java.lang.System.getenv;
import static java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset;
import static java.util.Collections.singletonMap;
import static org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.resourceToString;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

public class PropertiesUtils {

    public static Properties loadProperties() {
        return loadProperties(getenv("ENV"));
    }

    public static Properties loadProperties(String profile) {
        try {
            Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.putAll(getFlattenedMap(yaml.load(resourceToString("/application-config.yml", defaultCharset()))));
            if (profile != null)
                properties.putAll(getFlattenedMap(yaml.load(resourceToString(format("/application-config-%s.yml", profile), defaultCharset()))));
            return properties;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Cannot load properties", e);
        }
    }

    private static final Map<String, Object> getFlattenedMap(Map<String, Object> source) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        buildFlattenedMap(result, source, null);
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static void buildFlattenedMap(Map<String, Object> result, Map<String, Object> source, String path) {
        source.forEach((key, value) -> {
            if (!isBlank(path))
                key = path + (key.startsWith("[") ? key : '.' + key);
            if (value instanceof String) {
                result.put(key, value);
            } else if (value instanceof Map) {
                buildFlattenedMap(result, (Map<String, Object>) value, key);
            } else if (value instanceof Collection) {
                int count = 0;
                for (Object object : (Collection<?>) value)
                    buildFlattenedMap(result, singletonMap("[" + (count++) + "]", object), key);
            } else {
                result.put(key, value != null ? "" + value : "");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question is about accessing the content with .yaml and .properties file ***without*** using the Spring framework, ***however*** if you do have access to the Spring Framework in your classpath and don't mind using some internal classes, the following code can read the content in a very succinct fashion

For Properties file:

```
    File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:application.properties");
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new PathResource(file.toPath()));
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    // you now have properties corresponding to contents in the application.properties file in a java.util.Properties object
    Properties applicationProperties = propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();   
    // now get access to whatever property exists in your file, for example
    String applicationName = applicationProperties.getProperty("spring.application.name");
```

For a Yaml resource

```
    File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:application.yaml");
    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    factory.setResources(new PathResource(file.toPath()));
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    // you now have properties corresponding to contents in the application.yaml file in a java.util.Properties object
    Properties applicationProperties = factory.getObject();
    // now get access to whatever property exists in your file, for example
    String applicationName = applicationProperties.getProperty("spring.application.name");
```